# how to change data-tooltip message

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

is there a way i can control the data-tooltips message by using javascript? like html dom ?

```css
/* Add this attribute to the element that needs a tooltip */

[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Hide the tooltip content by default */

[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
/* Position tooltip above the element */

[data-tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px outset #C0C0C0;
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px #9F9F9F;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(206, 73%, 34%, 0.9);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
/* Triangle hack to make tooltip look like a speech bubble */

[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid hsla(206, 73%, 34%, 0.9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
/* Show tooltip content on hover */

[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" id="abc" data-tooltip="abc"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"/  ></a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can. The attribute text taken from the attribute `data-tooltip` using (`content: attr(data-tooltip)`).

So, you just need to change the attribute's value to whatever you want.

```js
function changeTooltip() {
  document.getElementById('abc').setAttribute('data-tooltip', 'aaa');
}
```

```css
/* Add this attribute to the element that needs a tooltip */

[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Hide the tooltip content by default */

[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
/* Position tooltip above the element */

[data-tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px outset #C0C0C0;
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px #9F9F9F;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(206, 73%, 34%, 0.9);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
/* Triangle hack to make tooltip look like a speech bubble */

[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid hsla(206, 73%, 34%, 0.9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
/* Show tooltip content on hover */

[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="abc" data-tooltip="abc"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"/  ></a>
<br />
<button onclick="changeTooltip()">Change tooltip to "aaa"</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

As explained in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes *data attributes* can be accessed through the `dataset` object, using the part of the attribute name after `data-`.

In your example:

```js
var tlink = document.getElementById('abc');
 
tlink.dataset.tooltip = "def";
```

```css
/* Add this attribute to the element that needs a tooltip */

[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Hide the tooltip content by default */

[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
/* Position tooltip above the element */

[data-tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px outset #C0C0C0;
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px #9F9F9F;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(206, 73%, 34%, 0.9);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
/* Triangle hack to make tooltip look like a speech bubble */

[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid hsla(206, 73%, 34%, 0.9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
/* Show tooltip content on hover */

[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="abc" data-tooltip="abc"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"/  ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('abc');

anchor.onmouseover = function(){
   this.setAttribute('data-tooltip', 'hello sir');
};
```

fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/omarCreativeDev/6rpxLu4p/